# Navigation Drawer Left spacing issue in kitkat

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

[image: lolipop device]

[image: kitkat device]

Here is my navigation view xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="start" 
    android:background="@color/android_default_white"     
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header" 
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" 
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black" 
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_bg"/>
```

In kitkat device left space before the icons are not coming..

Comment: can you post the code, please.

Comment: Asus Device checked in Redmi same issue because of KitKat OS

Comment: `<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/android_default_white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_bg"/>`

Comment: I dont know whether its a kitkat OS bug. If it is a bug and to workaround this, you could use the attribute app:actionLayout of the menu item, to set a custom layout for the drawer items.

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        int paddingPixel = 10;
        float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int paddingDp = (int)(paddingPixel * density);
        navigationView.setPadding(paddingDp,0,0,0);
    }
```

I resolved it by above code.